# Failed to convert @+drawable/thumb into a drawable

Tags: android, android-layout

I cannot see the Graphical layout and it shows the following error

```
Failed to convert @+drawable/thumb into a drawable
java.lang.NullPointerException
Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log
```

I tried restarting but it wont help... Any other way to solve this??

Comment: paste your logcat window here and your code

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't `@+drawable/thumb` be `@drawable/thumb` without the plus? If that is not the problem, please paste your `Window > Show View > Error Log` trace.